# Replace text in string efficiently

Tags: c#, regex

I have a c# string

```
((65.25 - 26.35)*420000)^2
```

i need to replace constant 2 with 2UL but the problem is the replace method replace all 2's with 2 UL for example it replace like this

```
((65.2long5 - 2long6.35)*42long0000)^2long
```

I need result like this

```
 ((65.25 - 26.35)*420000)^2long
```

how to replace efficiently so that other string don't get distrub

Comment: If it always looks like this you could replace "^2" with "^2long", but I think the better solution is the regex that someone posted as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a regex based replacement:

```
var res = Regex.Replace(str, @"(?<!\.)\b2\b(?!\.)", "2UL");
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C!%5C.)%5Cb2%5Cb(%3F!%5C.)&i=((65.25%20-%2026.35)*420000)%5E2&r=2UL)

*Details*:

- `(?<!\.)` - a negative lookbehind requiring the absence of a `.` before the current position
- `\b` - a leading word boundary
- `2`  - your value
- `\b` - a trailing word boundary
- `(?!\.)` - a negative lookahead that requires an absense of a `.` after the current position.

Comment: Wiktor Stribiże can you tell me the regex for this string
 SMA(20, V1) > 200000 AND C1 < LowerBollingerBand(20, 2)

I need to select only this using regex 

SMA(20,V1)  SMA(20, V1)  LowerBollingerBand(20, 2)

basically SMA, LowerBollingerBand is predefined and I want to select whatever comes in between bracket followed by predefined keywords which are SMA and LowerBollingerBand

Comment: Wouldn't it be better for you to post a separate question (together with what you tried)? You can earn points for a good question.

Comment: Ok doing it now